# Sending form input values with PHP to select an option in a list on following page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to send input values to another page with a select list. Is there anyway to have an option in the select drop down be selected based on the value of the inputs of the previous page?  Is this possible? I've tried to think and it doesn't seem like it's possible without JavaScript. Thanks for any help. I've included some code below may possibly be of help.

```
<form action="shoppingcart.php">
    <input name="bed_range" type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="bed_service" oninput="sliderChange(this.value);">
    <input name="bath_range" type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="bath_service" oninput="sliderChange2(this.value);">
    </form>

// then on following page

<select name="bdrms" class="calculate_bdrms" id="bdrms" onchange="">
        <option>One Bedroom Home</option>
        <option>Two Bedroom Home</option>
        <option>Three Bedroom Home</option>
        <option>Four Bedroom Home</option>
        <option>Five Bedroom Home</option>
        <option>Six Bedroom Home</option>
</select>
```

I want to be able to manipulate the selected option based on the input that was sent... is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can use sessions cookies for this for a serverside method.

Comment: Could you show me how? I'm on time constraints, and would love a refresher, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="shoppingcart.php">
    <input name="bed_range" type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="bed_service" oninput="sliderChange(this.value);">
    <input name="bath_range" type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="bath_service" oninput="sliderChange2(this.value);">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

For the next page; if you have a form like that the values will be in the URL and you can get it using `$_GET['name_of_input']`.

```
<?php
EDIT: As stated by FunkFortyNiner you should also check if the data is present or not to prevent errors. like 

if (isset($_GET['bed_range']) && !empty($_GET['bed_range'])) {
    $select1 = $_GET['bed_range']; 
}
if (isset($_GET['bath_range']) && !empty($_GET['bath_range'])) {
    $select2 = $_GET['bath_range'];
}     

//data is now $select1 and $select 2. Manipulate them however you like

?>

<select name="bdrms" class="calculate_bdrms" id="bdrms" onchange="">
        <option <?php if ( isset($select1) && $select1 === 1) echo 'selected';?> >One Bedroom Home</option>
        <option <?php if ( isset($select1) && $select1 === 2) echo 'selected';?>>Two Bedroom Home</option>
        <option <?php if ( isset($select1) && $select1 === 3) echo 'selected';?>>Three Bedroom Home</option>
        <option <?php if ( isset($select1) && $select1 === 4) echo 'selected';?>>Four Bedroom Home</option>
        <option <?php if ( isset($select1) && $select1 === 5) echo 'selected';?>>Five Bedroom Home</option>
        <option <?php if ( isset($select1) && $select1 === 6) echo 'selected';?>>Six Bedroom Home</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'd add an `isset() / !empty()` to the GET arrays/variables, since it will trigger an undefined index notice on initial pageload if used in the same file. That is entirely possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's highly appreciated.